# Does timeit clear the local memory after each iteration

Tags: python, numpy, timeit

I have a moderately sized sorted ascii text file that I am attempting to work with in Python.  I am trying to decide at what number of searches it becomes faster to read the entire file into memory and use numpy logical indexing to do searches instead of using a simple binary search function that I wrote using the timeit function.  To do this I have the following setup

```
import os
import timeit
import numpy as np


def binsearch(file, label, col=0, start=0, stop=None, linelength=None):

    if linelength is None:
        file.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)
        file.readline()
        linelength = file.tell()

    if stop is None:
        file.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
        stop = file.tell()

    stopline = stop // linelength
    startline = start // linelength

    midline = (stopline-startline) // 2 + startline

    mid = midline*linelength

    file.seek(mid, os.SEEK_SET)

    line = file.readline()

    if not line:
        return None

    linelab = int(line.split()[col])

    if linelab == label:
        return line
    elif midline == startline or midline == stopline:
        return None
    elif linelab < label:
        start = mid
        return binsearch(file, label, col=col, start=start, stop=stop, linelength=linelength)
    elif linelab > label:
        stop = mid
        return binsearch(file, label, col=col, start=start, stop=stop, linelength=linelength)


filepath = '/Users/aliounis/UCAC4/u4i/u4xtycho'
data0 = np.genfromtxt(filepath, dtype=np.int, names=['tycid', 'ucacid', 'rnm'])
numsearch = 10000
checks = data0['ucacid'][np.random.randint(0, 259788-1, numsearch)]
del data0

allin = """
data = np.genfromtxt(filepath, dtype=np.int, names=['tycid', 'ucacid', 'rnm'])

locate = checks.reshape(1, -1) ==  data['ucacid'].reshape(-1, 1)

print(data[np.any(locate, axis=1)].shape)
"""

bins = """
file = open(filepath, 'r')
recs = []
dtypes = np.dtype([('tycid', np.int), ('ucacid', np.int), ('rnm', np.int)])
for val in checks:
    line = binsearch(file, val, col=1)
    if line is not None:
        recs.append(np.array([tuple(np.fromstring(line, dtype=np.int, sep=' '))], dtype=dtypes))

print(np.concatenate(recs, axis=0).shape)
file.close()
"""
numattempts = 10
print(timeit.timeit(allin, number=numattempts, globals=globals())/numattempts)
print(timeit.timeit(bins, number=numattempts, globals=globals())/numattempts)
```

where I am using `timeit` to compare the average amount of time it takes to complete each task.  I want to know if this is a fair test, particularly to the numpy implementation.  Does timeit clear the local memory between each run (i.e. will it `del data` and `del locate` between each run number for the `allin` `timeit` call)?  I just want to be sure that I'm not accidentally forcing the numpy method to work in swap thus really slowing things down.

(note that the numpy array take up about 60MB when it is loaded so it being loaded a single time will not push into swap but if it is loaded many times things may start pushing into swap).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since timeit is implemented in regular Python it's quite easy to see what it does: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/timeit.py

To answer the question though, no, it will not execute a `del data` since that's not part of the statement or the setup method you are passing along to timeit. If you want that behaviour you should add it as a `setup` method.

In this specific case you reassign to the same value which results in a new memory block each time since timeit disabled the garbage collector by default.

Comment: So it doesn't implicitly get cleared, but from what is in the source code, the stuff that is passed to `timeit` is essentially run in a loop, therefore, the same variable is being used each iteration which implicitly gets rid of the old data I think (although I'm not sure if the memory is cleared before or after the statement is executed).

Comment: to make that last comment clearer, essentially what we get (in pseudo code) is `timer.start: for _ in range(number): x=np.genfrom...: timer.stop`.  I believe that the continued assignment should overwrite the memory as `genfromtxt` is called, therefore it isn't necessary to manually clear the `data` variable, unless I'm not understanding how the reassignment of the variable happens.

Comment: @Andrew, you're right the objects should get garbage collected when the variable is re-assigned (assuming no other references to the object). You'll have 2x mem usage at peak because object1 doesn't get garbage collected until object2 is done being assigned.

Comment: @BiRico: that's actually incorrect in the case of the timeit module. By default timeit temporarily disables the garbage collection so the results are not skewed.